# How to give up & down button in the grid

Tags: acumatica

Trying to implement up & down button to move the record in a grid. how to enable the option

[image]

Comment: are you trying to perform this on results on a custom page you created? if you are using linenbr in your DAC you can also use PXOrderedSelect for your view on your page and adjust the sortorder field (might need to add). This is just an alternative but this keeps your order of the records to. Look at SOOrderEntry and SOLine (Transactions view) for an example if it solves your question in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in ActionBar.

```
<CustomItems>
    <px:PXToolBarButton CommandSourceID="ds" CommandName="moveUpResults" Text="Row Up"
        Tooltip="Move Row Up">
        <Images Normal="main@ArrowUp" ></Images>
    </px:PXToolBarButton>
    <px:PXToolBarButton CommandSourceID="ds" CommandName="moveDownResults" Text="Row Down"
        Tooltip="Move Row Down">
        <Images Normal="main@ArrowDown" ></Images>
    </px:PXToolBarButton>
</CustomItems>
```

Comment: This will just add the buttons and icons, he will have to write the corresponding actions and hide them from action bar also